# How to generate all the subtrees expanded from the root node?

Tags: algorithm, subtree

I need an efficient algorithm to generate all the subtrees expanded from the root node. The algorithm should work for any tree structure. Can anyone contribute a code?

For example, given the edges of a tree as 0->1, 0->2, 2->3.
There are six subtrees:
0,

0,1

0,2

0,1,2

0,2,3

0,1,2,3

Comment: how are 0,1,2 and 0,1,2,3 subtrees? you didn't specify 1->2 in your spec

Comment: This might be clearer with pictures.

Comment: "0,1,2" means a subtree with two edges: "0->1" and "0->2"

Comment: I just found out that the "generating all trees" chapter from Knuth, Vol. 4 is available [out there](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww-cs-faculty.stanford.edu%2F~uno%2Ffasc4a.ps.gz&ei=6gX8T7KTOcfh4QTjhK2KBw&usg=AFQjCNGFPnsHAYgcsoaKZ2ieiwJ-pn6hiw). Could be an interesting read for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the TRIPS algorithm: [paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1183614.1183680)